# How to run a shell script on a Mac (10.7.4) to auto install updates?

Tags: mac, shell, script, updates

Im trying to run this shell script that is supposed to do this:

- This script uses the softwareupdate program on OSX to automatically check for updates and install them. It also logs all updates to the /Library/Management/update.log file.
- It first checks to see if there are any users logged in, and if so, logs the user in the log file and ends.
- If there is no user logged in, it updates the computer, logs the information, and reboots.

I keep getting this error:

```
update.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

update.sh: line 9: `fi'
```

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh    
users=$(users)
users1=$(echo "${#users}")
if [ $users1 -lt 1 ]    
then   
date >> /Library/Management/update.log && /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -aiv >> 
/Library/Management/update.log && /sbin/reboot    
else    
date >> /Library/Management/update.log && echo "Logged in users: " >> 
/Library/Management/update.log && echo $(users) >> /Library/Management/update.log    
fi
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `#!/bin/bash` instead of `!/bin/sh`. I have been told that there **may** be problem if the intended shell is not target, or the she-bang is not properly used. Especially if you intend to make it on auto-running scripts like corn-jobs (or some mac-os equivelent).

Comment: it does have the # but for some reason when I typed it into this page it wouldnt show up.

Comment: What about using `bash` instead of `sh`. Try it, `#!/bin/bash`. I never used a real MAC but a few months on hakintosh, I know that zsh or csh is mostly default shell on it. On linux default is bash.

Comment: Woah! Thanks for pointing out this awesome CLI tool `softwareupdate`. Never knew about it.

Answer (score 0):

The lines that start with `date` are missing line continuation characters. Replace them with something like this:

```
date >> /Library/Management/update.log && /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -aiv >> \
/Library/Management/update.log && /sbin/reboot
```

Comment: I still get the same error